# Does anybody know the formula for a quasicrystal structure?

Tags: geometry, irrational-numbers

I am an architecture student researching into quasicrystals with the hope of applying it to form a complex truss system. I was wondering if anyone new of a formula for the structure?  thanks in advance.

Jake

Comment: What do you mean by 'a formula for the structure'? The  most well-known way to generate a quasiperiodic structure is to consider a periodic structure in a higher dimension and then 'slice' it along a plane which is not aligned with any of the lattice directions (or any integer combinations of them).

Comment: if you want to know about the maths behind quasicrystals, look up "penrose tilings"

Comment: Still are you interested in the algorithm quasicrystal?

Answer (score 2):

Certainly there is no formula. However, take a look at http://www.tau.ac.il/~ronlif/quasicrystals.html and the book Marjorie Senechal, "Quasicrystals and geometry" (Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1995).

http://books.google.com/books/about/Quasicrystals_and_geometry.html?id=LdQ8AAAAIAAJ

as well as

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasicrystal

I do not see that any macroscopic use in engineering is possible at this time. There are algorithms to produce Penrose tilings correctly, but those are two dimensional patterns.